# как убрать границы у картинки&не появляется hover&как сделать заголовок по середине

Tags: html, css, html5

1.Здраствуйте,это мои 3 вопроса,если вам не сложно ответьте на мои вопросы:>

1.Первое-как убрать границу у картинки?Она там недолжна быть.

```css
.film1{
margin-top: 15px;
margin-left: 20px;
border: 2px solid;
float: left;

}
.flex{
display:flex;
}

.text{
text-indent: 200;
}
.knopka:hover{
font-size: 20px;
background-color: blue;
}
.image{
width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <HEAD>
        <link href="css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>сборище</title>
    </HEAD>
<body> 
    <div class="flex">
             
             <div class="film1">
             <img class="image" src="https://kinokrad.co/uploads/img/tb/974fdf2e4ef2f92759365ac7d19089c5.jpeg">
             <b><br>1.Название мультфильма-Маша и медведь. <br>2.Жанр:Детский телевизионный сериал.<br>3.Первая серия: 18 января 2009 г.</b>
<a href="https://kinokrad.co/334069-masha-i-medved-leto-s-mashey.html" target="_blank">
<buttom class="knopka">

<br> <b>Смотреть сейчас</b>

</buttom>
</a>

</div>
</div>
</div>

   
</body>
</html>
```

2.у меня не появляется hover код выше.

3.как сделать заголовок по середине?

Comment: 1. img{border: none;}
2. Тег называется не buttom, a button  [читать тут](http://htmlbook.ru/html/button)
3. Выравнивание текста свойство: text-align  [читать тут](http://htmlbook.ru/css/text-align)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) я не очень понял о какой границе речь. Если о бордюре, то вы не указали цвет, а он по умолчанию задается.

2)Вы присваиваете его не тому элементу. И ждете что потомки его унаследуют.

3)Заголовок делать как-то так

```css
body{margin:0;}

.film1 {
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 20px;
 /*border: 2px solid;*/
 /* float: left;*/
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}


.knopka{
  display:block;
  margin:10px 0;
  max-width:150px;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:20px;
}
.text_title{
width:100%;
text-align: center;
font-size:20px;
}
.knopka:hover {
  color:#fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.image {
  width: 35px;
}

.text_strong{
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">

  <div class="film1">
    <img class="image" src="https://kinokrad.co/uploads/img/tb/974fdf2e4ef2f92759365ac7d19089c5.jpeg">
<p class="text_title">Title</p>
    <p>1.Название мультфильма-Маша и медведь. <br>2.Жанр:Детский телевизионный сериал.<br>3.Первая серия: 18 января 2009 г.</p>
    <a href="https://kinokrad.co/334069-masha-i-medved-leto-s-mashey.html" target="_blank">
      <buttom class="knopka">

        <span class="text_strong">Смотреть сейчас</span>

      </buttom>
    </a>

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```